# Preparation of an aqueous solution of rubidium azide from rubidium chloride

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I want to start with $\ce{RbCl}$ and end up with pure rubidium azide in solution.

If I had rubidium sulfate, the following would be possible (from Wiki):

$$\ce{Rb2SO4 + Ba(N3)2 ->  2RbN3 + BaSO4}$$

The $\ce{BaSO4}$ is a precipitate and can be filtered off

Also from Wiki:

$$\ce{H2SO4 + RbCl -> RbHSO4 + HCl}$$

Would $\ce{RbHSO4}$ work with the barium azide reaction? What other reaction products would be present?

Is there any way of getting rid of residual $\ce{H2SO4}$ and $\ce{HCl}$?

Comment: Increase the concentration of RbCl and you'll get Rb2SO4.

Comment: Any azide preparation with an acid soln runs the risk of creating hydrazoic acid HN3 which is a hazardous gas.

Comment: @Waylander I agree. Azide compounds are generally unstable and prone to decomposition adding to the hazard factor. They are also toxic.

Comment: What about converting rubidium chloride to sulphate by anion exchange resin in sulphate cycle ?

Comment: I am not familiar with ion exchange ( being an electronics engineer rather than a chemist). Could you please give me some links to explain further. The reason I need to start withe rubidium chloride, is that I need to use separated isotopes(Rb87 and Rb85) and these are only available as the chloride. Application is filling cells for rubidium atomic clock